# onTextChangedListener goes into loop, but only on first ListView element, any following elements don't loop

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a moneyConversion class which converts strings as I type them into an EditText which there are multiple of due to being contained in a listview. The conversion works fine for the EditText, but for some reason, the first list item always goes into a loop and hangs when typing something in, where as all other identical EditText boxes work absolutely fine and format without issue.

Here's my adapter.

```
public class DietyAmountAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Dieties> data = null;
    int counterTotal;
    int currentlyActive;


    public DietyAmountAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Dieties> data){
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }


    public void addViews(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentlyActive = 0;
        this.clear();
        for(int i = 1; i <= counterTotal; i++) {
            boolean a = sharedPref.getBoolean(Integer.toString(i), false);
            if (a) {
                currentlyActive = currentlyActive + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View ListItem = convertView;

        Holder holder;

        final Dieties Diety = data.get(position);


        if (ListItem == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            ListItem = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new Holder();
            holder.banner = (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.DietyBanner);
            holder.title = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
            holder.text1 = (EditText) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.text1Amount);
            holder.text2 = (EditText) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.text2Amount);
            holder.text1Text = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.text1Text);
            holder.text2Text = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.text2Text);

            ListItem.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (Holder) ListItem.getTag();
        }


        MyTextWatcher text2Watcher = (new MyTextWatcher() {

            public Holder holder;

            public void setView(Holder newHolder){
                holder = newHolder;
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (holder.text2.isFocused()) {
                    holder.text2.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    String raw = moneyConversion.unformatToString(s.toString());
                    double text1Value = moneyConversion.gettext1Value(Double.parseDouble(raw));
                    holder.text2.setText(moneyConversion.formatLive(raw));
                    holder.text1.setText(moneyConversion.format(text1Value));
                    holder.text2.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        MyTextWatcher text1Watcher = (new MyTextWatcher() {

            public Holder holder;

            public void setView(Holder newHolder){
                holder = newHolder;
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (holder.text1.isFocused()) {
                    holder.text1.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    String text1Value = moneyConversion.unformatToString(s.toString());
                    String formattedValue = moneyConversion.formatLive(text1Value);
                    double text2Value = moneyConversion.gettext2Value(Double.parseDouble(text1Value));
                    holder.text1.setText(formattedValue);
                    holder.text2.setText(moneyConversion.format(text2Value));
                    holder.text1.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });


        HolderOnFocusChangeListener text1FocusListener = new HolderOnFocusChangeListener() {

            public DietyAmountAdapter.Holder holder;

            public void setHolder(Holder newHolder){
                holder = newHolder;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
//                Timer timer = new Timer();
//                TimerTask t1 = new TimerTask() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void run() {
//                        holder.text1.clearFocus();
//                    }
//                };

                if (hasFocus){
                    holder.text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5aa0ce"));
                    holder.text1Text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5aa0ce"));
                    holder.text1.setSelection(holder.text1.getText().length());

                }
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    if (!holder.text1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        holder.text1.setSelection(holder.text1.getText().length());
//                        holder.text2.setText(moneyConversion.format());
                    }

                    holder.text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#424242"));
                    holder.text1Text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#424242"));

//                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(runOnUiThread(t1), 1, 500);

                }
            }
        };

        HolderOnFocusChangeListener text2FocusListener = new HolderOnFocusChangeListener() {

            public DietyAmountAdapter.Holder holder;

            public void setHolder(Holder newHolder){
                holder = newHolder;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
//                Timer timer = new Timer();
//                TimerTask t2 = new TimerTask() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void run() {
//                        holder.text2.clearFocus();
//                    }
//                };
                if (hasFocus){
                    holder.text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5aa0ce"));
                    holder.text2Text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5aa0ce"));
                    holder.text2.setSelection(holder.text2.getText().length());
                }
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    if (!holder.text2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        holder.text2.setSelection(holder.text2.getText().length());
                    }
                    holder.text2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#424242"));
                    holder.text2Text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#424242"));

                }
            }
        };

        text2FocusListener.setHolder(holder);
        text1FocusListener.setHolder(holder);
        text1Watcher.setView(holder);
        text2Watcher.setView(holder);

        holder.text2.addTextChangedListener(text2Watcher);
        holder.text1.addTextChangedListener(text1Watcher);

        holder.text2.setOnFocusChangeListener(text2FocusListener);
        holder.text1.setOnFocusChangeListener(text1FocusListener);

        holder.title.setText(Diety.title);
        holder.banner.setImageResource(Diety.banner);


        return ListItem;
    }
    static class Holder {
        ImageView banner;
        TextView title;
        EditText text1;
        EditText text2;
        TextView text2Text;
        TextView text1Text;
    }
}
```

Here's my moneyConversion class:

```
    public class moneyConversion {

    public int currentlyActive;
    public int counterTotal;
    Context context;

    public static double gettext1Value(double value){
        double newValue = (value / 1.05);
        return newValue;
    }

    public static double gettext2Value(double value){
        double newValue = (value * 1.05);
        return newValue;
    }
    public static String format(double value){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.applyPattern("###,###,###,###.##");
        String formattedValue = df.format(value);
        Log.d(TAG, formattedValue);
        return formattedValue;

    }

    public static String formatLive(String s) {
        if (s.endsWith(".")) {
            return s;
        }

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.applyPattern("###,###,###,###.##");
        Double value = Double.parseDouble(s);
        String formattedValue = df.format(value);
//        Log.d(TAG, formattedValue);
        return formattedValue;
    }

    public static double unformat(String s){
        if (s != null && s.isEmpty() ){
            return 0;
        }
        String string = s.replace(",", "");

        if (string.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
//        if (string.equals(".")){
//            return Double.parseDouble("0");
//        }


        return Double.parseDouble(string);
    }

    public static String unformatToString(String s){
            if (s != null && s.isEmpty() ){
                return "0";
            }
            String string = s.replace(",", "");

            if (string.isEmpty()) {
                return "0";
            }
//        if (string.equals(".")){
//            return Double.parseDouble("0");
//        }


            return string;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your textchangeListener inside `if (ListItem == null) {` condition block, it will work.

What actually happening in your case is whenever you scroll your listview on change listener will call for each and every row that is visible.